# How to check whether compression is enabled in gzip/deflate serverside from client (browser)

Tags: performance

How to check whether compression is enabled in gzip/deflate serverside from client (browser) by seeing the http request. Whether content served is zipped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `Content-Encoding` header to see what kind of compression was used by the server.  Note that the server will only use compression if the browser has sent an `Accept-Encoding` header, and the server supports at least one of the encodings in this list.

For example, if the browser supplies `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate` and the server supports gzip encoding, it will reply with the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header and a gzip-compressed entity.